# Rewrite 301 redirect rules to move everything up a category

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to create a rewrite rule to move everything up a category:

example:

**from:**

> /category/second-category/product-name.html
>
> /category/second-category/third-category/product-name.html

**to:**

> /second-category/product-name.html
>
> /second-category/third-category/product-name.html

I've changed the structure around and need to add 501 redirects and only know how to do per-one and don't fancy doing 200+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?:cat1|cat2|cat5)/(.+?\.html)$ /$1
```

Comment: Can we apply a rule so it works only on certain categories as site has loads links etc.. so maybe /root/(do some magic) /root2/(more magic)

Comment: yes sure, see updated answer. It will only apply to `cat1` or `cat2` or `cat5` now.

Comment: Just make sure this is placed as first rule in your root .htaccess

Comment: Oh seems to not be playing ball after some testing :) Can i share the URL with yourself and your see what i mean. I get 404 not found as i move around the structure..

Comment: Yes do share the URL but 404 might be a different problem as your code might not be liking top category missing from URL.

Comment: beanbags.ambientlounge.com - RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?:interior-bean-bags|outdoor-bean-bags|kids-bean-bags)/(.+?\.html)$ /$1 is what im using

Comment: i was placing /ambient-lounge/ after interiors as that was the old url, all we removed was the sub-category and always after /main/ like /interior-bean-bags/sub-category(now removed)/....

Comment: For ex: your rule will remove `interior-bean-bags` from URL but `http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/acoustic-sofa/` will cause 404

Comment: Oh so those options are to remove it... ahh let me try the other way around :)

Comment: I changed to: RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?:ambient-lounge|pimp|lelbys-bean-bags|cocoon-couture)/(.+?\.html)$ /$1 but product pages dont work